# Angular app logs out automatically even after Access Tokens renewal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

Our organization has an Identityserver4 implementation with the implicit flow, which we use as an SSO provider.
It's being used by 3 of our apps. All of them use angular as front-end.

One of the app gets signed out after every 1 Hr, even when OIDC client library renews the access token.

In the identityServer configuration, `AccessTokenLifeTime` is set to 900 seconds and `IdentityTokenLifeTime` set to 3600 seconds (1 Hr).

Tried changing the `IdentityTokenLifeTime` to one day, and it worked but feels like that just delays the problem not fixing it properly.
Does anyone have any idea why maybe the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: _set to 86400 seconds (1 Hr)_ is one day, not 1 hour btw. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, it was a typo.

Comment: May I ask what you are doing with the id token? It's expiry should be rather irrelevant since you use access tokes for pass to an API and refresh tokens to retrieve it. Id tokens shouldn't actually be sent to the backend

Comment: Standard life time of the Id token is five minutes and the access token is an hour. Circumnavigating security isnt a good idea unless you really know what you are doing. Your application should either enable sliding access token or you should handle refreshing the access.

Comment: Did you enable the silent renew mechanism of oidc-client?

Comment: @RaulAlonso Yes I did

Comment: You have to ensure your identityserver session is still valid when silent renew occurs. Implicit flow specification does not allow to refresh the tokens, but IdSrv can recreate them for you if you are still logged in (to Identity server).

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks, Fixed the issue by enabling sliding cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by enabling `Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration`  by,

```
services.AddIdentityServer((option) =>
        {
            option.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = true;

        })
```